# Not able to do sudo on server

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, root

modified `sudoers.d` manually through `vi` command.

Below is the result when I do `ls -l /etc | grep sudoers`

```
-r--r----- 1 root root     786 Apr 12 12:36 sudoers
drwxr-x--- 2 root root    4096 Apr 12 12:42 sudoers.d
```

But I am not able to do `sudo`

```
sudo su
>>> /etc/sudoers.d/hduser: syntax error near line 4 <<<
sudo: parse error in hduser near line 4
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Tried restarting the instance from AWS UI, still the file is not recoverable.
Don't have root password, so the file is not modifiable manually.

Comment: try this https://serverfault.com/questions/251213/repair-a-broken-sudoers-file or https://serverfault.com/questions/206610/ubuntu-borked-my-sudoers-file-how-can-i-fix-it

Comment: Tried this, but didnt work

Comment: I'm not familiar with AWS, but I think it could be possible to run another Ubuntu instance where to mount the current one and recover (remove) this broken file.